# LimitAllocationPerApp Object in Salesforce

Tags: limits

Does anyone know how to use this object for the following -

App quotas for API limits enable you to reserve API capacity for mission-critical connected apps or set a ceiling for API usage of non-critical connected apps.

This object was part of this pilot - https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Spring14/Allocate+API+Limit+App+Quotas